# AccessViolationException, IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8.5

we are 4 developers (not professional server administrators) and running 2 servers with IIS 8.5 (Windows server 2012 R2) and ASP.NET 4.

Multiple times per day we get this exception in the windows event log:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIsLastNotification(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIsLastNotification(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequestNotification(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletionHelper(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletion(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

The next entry in the event log is this:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: iiscore.dll, version: 8.5.9600.17224, time stamp: 0x53b1e5a1
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000002c44
Faulting process id: 0x257c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d05f0c93813e6e
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\iiscore.dll
Report Id: 073f9a19-cb13-11e4-80c3-0cc47a02ce53
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The always occur as a pair. I spent hours with google but have no idea if this is a problem in our code or in an external module and how to solve is. The main problem is that one of our servers stops responding from time to time, so I am really interested if this problems belong together.

We log all exceptions, but I cannot find it in our log. I also tried to attach the remote debugger, but I dont get the exception and the debugging really slows down the website.

---

Edit: I checked all sources to catch exceptions in m application:

- AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
- TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException
- Custom Owin Middleware

But I could not find this exception. The next thing I am gonna try is a custom http module. Lets see.

I also found some not warnings in the event log like:

```
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
```

or

```
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
```

These can happen very often, I am confused why they are added to the event log.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an ASPNET access problem.

Right-click "Computer" --> "Manage"--> "Local Users and Groups" --> "Groups"

Find the "DB2ADMNS" and "DB2USERS" groups.

Add the "ASPNET" user to each of those groups.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I cannot find these users. We also use a domain server and the application pool has a custom user.

Comment: You do not have to find it, its a system account. Just add ASPNET there and should enable enough access for ASP.

Comment: Are you sure? DB2 is a database and when I google for DB2ADMNS I only find the document from IBM, like this one: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0011930.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-0-2-0-13-2&lang=en

Comment: When you say 'cannot find these users' you mean the DB groups or the ASPNET user ? ASP user is hidden, not normally visible, but DB groups should be there (may be named differently like DBADMINS and DBUSERS, but they should exist in some form).

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand it. Why DB2ADMNS? We dont have no sql-database-engine installed and there is no user group with this name.

Comment: If it's not a DB at fault, the Hotfix 908521 may be. If that is installed and RPC over HTTP proxy networking is enabled, that exact error will occur.

Comment: The hotfix is quite old and automatic updates are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be concerned about

> Exception type: HttpException  Exception message: The remote host
>   closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.

That just means that the remote side went away (crashed? lost connectivity?  who knows) while it was receiving data.

I also wouldn't worry about

> Exception type: HttpException  Exception message: A potentially
>   dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

That just means your URL includes a colon, which isn't allowed.

So that leaves the top two error messages.  The problem is somewhere in your custom app.

> Exception code: 0xc0000005

is an access violation.  Either your application's account doesn't have access to everything it needs (application pool? files?) or it attempted to access protected memory.  (Someone on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/579004/w3wp-exe-crash-rewrite-dll-iis-7-5) suggested the problem might also be faulty memory.)  [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) (and/or a memory testing utility) can probably help you track down what's causing the issue.

Good luck!